# SCSS the value of the variable depends on the resolution

Tags: css, sass

i have 3 SCSS variables

```
$angle-px: 120px;
$sections-gap: 30px;
$sections-calculated-gap: -($angle-px - $sections-gap);
```

and then im using it that way

```
 margin-top: $sections-calculated-gap;
```

I need to set by default `$angle-px: 40px` and if resolution is big, for example

```
@media (min-width: 1200px) {}
```

need to set it to 120px, any idea? Thanks

Comment: Have you looked into CSS variables.

Answer (score 0):

Already figured it out. Used css variables instead